# What language is this Salesforce code that I need to wrap?

Tags: url, parameters, salesforce

I'm working on a Salesforce coding issue. Let me preface this by saying I'm not a developer or Salesforce expert.

1. What language is this?

   ```
    Data Type   FormulaThis formula references multiple objects      
    IF (Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c <> "" && CONTAINS(Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c, "qualtrics"),

    Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c &

    (IF (CONTAINS(Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c,"?SID="), "&", "?")) &

    (IF (CONTAINS(TEXT(Type__c), "Site Visit"),
    "ContactId="&Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Contact__c&
    "&CoachType="&SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Work_Type__r.Name," ","%20")&
    "&CoachName="&SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c," ","%20")&
    "&InitPartId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Id&
    "&InstitutionName="&substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(Institution_Name__c," ","%20"),")",""),"(","")&
    "&AccountId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Participating_Institution__r.Id&
    "&TodaysDate="&TEXT(TODAY())&
    "&SOWLineItemId="&Id&
    "&LeaderCollege="&Initiative_Participation__r.ATD_Leader_College_Status__c&
    "&SVRCompleted="&TEXT(Count_of_Site_Visit_Fulfillments__c)&
    "&SVRRequired="&TEXT(Number_of_Work_Units_Allocated__c),

    IF (CONTAINS(TEXT(Type__c), "Feedback"),
    "InitPartId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Id&
    "&SOWLineItemId="&Id&
    "&ReportYear="&Statement_of_Work__r.SOW_Year__c&
    "&UserId="&Contractor_User_Id__c&
    "&InstitutionName="&substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(Institution_Name__c," ","%20"),")",""),"(",""),
    "")
    ))

    ,"")
   ```
2. Essentially it's pulling a link from another product we've integrated it with. We then take the basic link and reformat it to add parameters.

The problem is when it pulls in some parameters (ex: CoachName) the Coach entered their name in strange formats like: John (Coach) Doe.

So when the script outputs a URL that includes parameters it breaks at the `&CoachName=John%20(Coach)%` portion of the URL. Any easy way to work around this by modifying the script? Unfortunately we DO need that (Coach) identifier because the system we push to grabs that as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's [formula syntax](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5), I'd compare it to Excel-like formulas. There's [self-paced training](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) if you don't want to read documentation. And as it's not exactly code-related you may have more luck on dedicated site, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. More admins lurk there.

So you do want that "(Coach)" to go through but it breaks the link? Looks like `(` is a [special character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding). It's not technically wrong to have unescaped parentheses, if it breaks that other site you might want to contact them and get their act together. RFC doesn't force us to encode them but looks like you'll have to to solve it at least in the short term: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/is-it-bad-to-use-parentheses-in-a-url

Instead of poor man's encoding (`SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c," ","%20")` try using proper [`URLENCODE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c)`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlencode.htm&type=5).

Or there's bit more "pro" function called [URLFOR](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlfor.htm&type=5) but the documentation doesn't make it very clear how powerful the 3rd parameter is with the braces `[key1 = value1, key2 = value2]` syntax. Basically just pass the parameters and let SF worry about encoding special characters etc.

Read my answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46445/799 and there are some examples on the net like https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DFS-URL-buttons-for-Lightning-basic-setup-limitations?language=en_US&rsc_301

Comment: Yes for now we do want "(Coach)" to pass through.  But it breaks the "clickable" hyperlink that's provide via reports, and emails to staff.  The workaround is to highlight the entire hyperlink even though only half is "clickable" and paste it in your web browser which does work.  But we can't rely on staff to do that.  They simply report back "the link doesn't work" not realizing what's happening.  Removing the parenthesis around coach would be hugely impactful because so many things are looking for that wording with parenthesis up and downstream in Salesforce.  Poor coding no doubt!

Comment: So the easiest thing would be to figure out how we can make that link clickable.  Below is an example of the link that gets broken because of the parenthesis...    https://redacted.com/jfe/form/SV_3JjFpMRH8XdunTT?ContactId=003U0000009FT0I&CoachType=ATD%20Leadership%20Coach&CoachName=Zaul%20Echrist&InitPartId=a0l0B00001KUdaA&InstitutionName=Bo%20State%20Community%20College%20TN&AccountId=0010A00001n7cT5&TodaysDate=2022-08-23&SOWLineItemId=a1d4O00000FUgN1&LeaderCollege=&SVRCompleted=1&SVRRequired=1

Comment: So, have you tried swapping `SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c," ","%20")` with `URLENCODE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c)`?

Comment: Here is the error I received...   Error: Function URLENCODE may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: What is this formula? A custom formula field on the record, custom button, custom link, a field created kind of on the fly just in 1 particular report?

Comment: Custom field definition in Salesforce.  > Simple formula?

Comment: I'm not in love with this stack overflow interface.  I reposted the question to the salesforce stack exchange and I think I did a better job of explaining myself including screenshots.  If you care to look:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383787/salesforce-coding-issue-seems-simple-to-fix-but-who-knows